# Form validation fails but submits page

Tags: javascript, validation, dom-events, onsubmit

I have a form which uses GET as the method. I want to do some js validation on the form. I bind the event using

```
document.forms[0].onsubmit = function(){return myObj.myFrm.isFormValid();}.
```

In Firefox it works the first time I click on submit but after a while if I click it again the form submits even though I've not changed and data.

Any ideas?

Comment: What if you bind the function in the HTML onsubmit attribute on the form tag instead of assigning it in JavaScript.

Comment: does the same thing. Fails the first time (displays error message) second click it submits the page

Comment: Can you clear up some of the details?  When you say "it works" the first time but in the comment about say it "Fails" the first time ("displays error message").. what do you mean?  What is the error message?  Where is the definition of myFrm and isFormValid()?

Comment: What if you reassign it to onsubmit at the end of validation?

Comment: Have you considered using jQuery? ;)

Answer (score -1):

Simply adding an event handler doesn't stop it from submitting.

You need to add in `preventDefault();`

([Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.preventDefault))

Comment: Adding an event handler works in the simple test cases I tried. (But then again I don't know what isFormValid looks like.)